# Storage of Sweet Potato Pie

Tags: storage-method, vegetables, pie

I want to make [Sweet Potato Pie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_potato_pie) for the first time for Monday yet I'm going to be busy on the weekend. This got me wondering what are proper storage ideas for Sweet Potato Pie. For instance if I make the pie tomorrow would it taste just as good for Monday if I freeze it after it cools and defrost it Sunday night? Or are there other methods I should utilize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've frozen custard pies and they keep well. Be a bit careful when defrosting: if you leave it out in a humid environment, condensation will soak into the crust and make it soggy. Some tips: wrap some foil around the crust on the edges, freeze in a bag,and defrost in the fridge (still in bag). After it is defrosted (at least mostly), keep the foil in place and put it into a hot oven for 5-10 minutes to crisp up the crust and dry out any condensation that has formed.

I've kept pies for a week, and there were no issues. I imagine they will keep for something between 1 and 3 weeks if refrigerated, so there is no reason to freeze if you plan to eat them within a week.

Answer (score 1):

The liquid weeping out is called synerisis. Xanthan gum is generally useful in reducing it, but I can't tell you what amount would be right to add to pumpkin pie. Too much would make the pumpkin custard gummy.